# Can't set a NativeExpressAdView visibility to GONE

Tags: java, android

If I do the simple:

```
            nativeAd = (NativeExpressAdView) mActivity.findViewById(R.id.adView);
            nativeAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
```

I see a native ad. But if I add `nativeAd.setVisibility(LinearLayout.GONE);` and after a button click I do `nativeAd.setVisibility(LinearLayout.VISIBLE);` I get in LogCat the two warnings:

```
            Received error HTTP response code: 403
            There was a problem getting an ad response. ErrorCode: 0
```

What do I do wrong? I wan't the add to appear at the same screen only if the user clicks on a button in another activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it interests anyone - just put the native ad in a layout, and make the layout GONE.

Answer (score 0):

Put NativeExpressAdView inside of a LinearLayout for example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/llad"
android:visibility="invisible"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent">
<com.google.android.gms.ads.NativeExpressAdView
    android:id="@+id/ad_View"
    android:layout_gravity="center|top"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-your_id"
    ads:adSize="FULL_WIDTHx80">
</com.google.android.gms.ads.NativeExpressAdView>
 </LinearLayout>
```

in class:

```
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.adese, parent, false);
        final NativeExpressAdView adView = (NativeExpressAdView) view.findViewById(R.id.ad_View);
        final LinearLayout lld = (LinearLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.llad);
        adView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        lld.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder()
                .addTestDevice("your_device_number")
                .build();
        adView.loadAd(request);
        adView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAdLoaded() {
                super.onAdLoaded();
                adView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                lld.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });
```

Works this way for me!